# How to get Test Activity Logs from Selenium Grid 2 programatically?

Tags: java, grid, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch Selenium Grid2 programatically, and I also know that Grid API has a LoggerManager. But I am not sure how to implement a custom logger for it or get the selenium node logs at the Gird Hub end.

Either,

> I need a way to get Selenium Grid 2 Node logs as part of Selenium Hub
>   logs

or

> I need a way to get all test activity logged at Selenium Hub end

By test activity I mean activity log of all the calls to JsonWire rest service and responses
.

How can this be done?

I am running Selenium Grid using following code

```
import org.openqa.grid.web.Hub;
import org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.GridHubConfiguration;

public class GridHub {

    private String host = "localhost";
    private Integer port = 4444;
    Hub gridHub = null;
    GridHubConfiguration gridHubConfig = new GridHubConfiguration();

    GridHub() {
        gridHubConfig.setHost(host);
        gridHubConfig.setPort(port);
        gridHub = new Hub(gridHubConfig);        
            gridHub.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java contains a getLog command which might help.

So from the HUB, you'd send a `http://node/selenium-server/driver?cmd=getLog` or getLogMessages to the node, which will return the logs for the current session (LoggingManager.perSessionLogHandler().getLog(sessionId))

At this point you have access to the node's log on the hub.

Hope this helps?